# Php, is there an event when a constant is defined?

Tags: php

so, whenever something like this happens:

```
define('YAY', 324);
```

I want to have a Closure which executes and tells me a new constant is defined.
Dont ask why I need this though :)

Comment: How do you want that to be told?

Comment: You'll need to add a layer of indirection before `define` is called, via your own wrapper

Comment: for example, is there a php function like "register_constant_being_declared(function($name, $value) { });"

Comment: Why keep the application of this a secret?

Comment: The problem with not telling us why you want this is that we can't spot if this is an example of "the X/Y Problem" - there may be a better solution to your underlying requirement than your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "no". PHP has no built-in "hooks" that run callbacks during execution of specific types of statement.

A few ideas come to mind:

- create your own function, `define_and_run_hook`, and do a find-and-replace across all your current code
- learn how to create a "zend extension" in C, which hooks into the engine's implementation of `define` and adds a hook
- play with namespaces - you can (I think) create a function called `Foo\define` which will be run when you write `define` within the namespace `Foo`, or after a `use function Foo\define`